# BluetoothProfile of Paired android device

Tags: android, bluetooth

is there any way to get the Profile of a paired blutooth device.
i have been able to pair a bluetooth device and it has been paired as INPUT_DEVICE
in android, i get the Object of BluetoothDevice for that , which contains the address and other things, but if the android has stored it's profile then from where we can get the paired device profile , like is it HEADSET or A2DP or INPUT_DEVICE or other.

i have already tried the method of service listener

```
private BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener listener=new BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(int profile) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //if(profile==BluetoothProfile.HEADSET)
                headSet=null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(int profile, BluetoothProfile proxy) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch(profile){
            case BluetoothProfile.HEADSET:
                Log.e("found","headset");
                break;
            case BluetoothProfile.A2DP:
                Log.e("found","a2dp");
                activity.onA2DPListenr((BluetoothA2dp) proxy);
                break;
            case BluetoothProfile.HEALTH:
                Log.e("found","HEALTH");
                break;
            }


            }
        }
    };
```

now whenever i call it via

```
activity.getAdapter().getProfileProxy(activity, listener,
                BluetoothProfile.HEADSET);
```

it'll go to headset log, and when i call with

```
activity.getAdapter().getProfileProxy(activity, listener,
                BluetoothProfile.HEALTH);
```

it'll go to health log, and shows that the profile has been connected for same device.but the same device can bot be both.

also my requirment totally different from this, i don't want to try different scenarios to find out the actual profile of my paired device which android already contains, is their any way to get the actual profile..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the bluetooth profile or service associated with the BluetoothDevice can be found by

```
    boolean hasLatestUuids=device.fetchUuidsWithSdp();
            if(hasLatestUuids){
/*getUuids() return cached uuids so we need to make an sdp request to get refresh uuid associated with the device*/
                ParcelUuid[] uu=device.getUuids();
                for(ParcelUuid u:uu){
                    Log.e("found","uuid "+u.getUuid());
                }
            }
```

we can also make request via reflection as:

```
Method m=null;
        boolean hasLatestUuid=false;
        try {
            m=BluetoothDevice.class.getDeclaredMethod("fetchUuidsWithSdp", null);
            m.setAccessible(true);
            hasLatestUuid=(Boolean) m.invoke(device, null);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ParcelUuid[] uuids=null;
if(hasLatestUuid){
    try {
        m=device.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getUuids", null);
        m.setAccessible(true);
        uuids=(ParcelUuid[]) m.invoke(device, null);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(uuids!=null){
        for(ParcelUuid u:uuids){
            Log.e("found","uuid "+u.describeContents());
            Log.e("found","uuid "+u.getUuid());
        }
    }
```

here the log return the uuids list supported by the remote device, for example in my case i need to connect to two different devices , first one with HID profile and second with serial port or socket, so

for serial port device i am getting uuid:00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

for HumanInterface i am getting uuid:00001124-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

it has bas_uuid:00000000-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB
and for serialPort:0x1101
and for HID:0x1124

all these information can be found http://bluetooth-pentest.narod.ru/doc/assigned_numbers_-_service_discovery.html

we can also check this via BluetoothClass i.e

```
public static final int PROFILE_HEADSET = 0;
/** @hide */
public static final int PROFILE_A2DP = 1;
/** @hide */
public static final int PROFILE_OPP = 2;
/** @hide */
public static final int PROFILE_HID = 3;
/** @hide */
public static final int PROFILE_PANU = 4;
/** @hide */
public static final int PROFILE_NAP = 5;


BluetoothClass myClass=device.getBluetoothClass();
        int val=myClass.getDeviceClass();
        Log.e("found","class "+val);
        Log.e("found","class "+(val|bitmask));

        Log.e("found","PROFILE_HEADSET:"+doesclassMatch(PROFILE_HEADSET,myClass));
        Log.e("found","PROFILE_A2DP:"+doesclassMatch(PROFILE_A2DP,myClass));
        Log.e("found","PROFILE_OPP:"+doesclassMatch(PROFILE_OPP,myClass));
        Log.e("found","PROFILE_HID:"+doesclassMatch(PROFILE_HID,myClass));
        Log.e("found","PROFILE_PANU:"+doesclassMatch(PROFILE_PANU,myClass));
        Log.e("found","PROFILE_NAP:"+doesclassMatch(PROFILE_NAP,myClass));




private boolean doesclassMatch(int profile,BluetoothClass myClass){
    Method m=null;
    try {
        m=BluetoothClass.class.getMethod("doesClassMatch", new Class[]{int.class});
        m.setAccessible(true);
        return (Boolean) m.invoke(myClass, profile);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;

}
```

it'll return true for particular type or service the device contain.

but as per BluetoothClass specification:

```
BluetoothClass is useful as a hint to roughly describe a device
 * (for example to show an icon in the UI), but does not reliably describe which
 * Bluetooth profiles or services are actually supported by a device. Accurate
 * service discovery is done through SDP requests, which are automatically
 * performed when creating an RFCOMM socket with 
 * BluetoothDevice#createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord} and 
 * BluetoothAdapter#listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord
```

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/4f868ed/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass.java

Comment: Hi Can you tell me where did you get the values `public static final int PROFILE_HEADSET = 0;
/** hide */
public static final int PROFILE_A2DP = 1;
/** hide */
public static final int PROFILE_OPP = 2;` etc? What are the values for HSP, HFP and AVRCP?

Comment: I am developing an application which connects to only A2DP, AVRCP, HFP and HSP profiles. How can i check if a found device is any of the mentioned profiles.